# IOS/Swift: How to indicate the first position of the $0 in the .firstIndex ? 'Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String''

Tags: arrays, swift, array-indexing

I would like to search a value in an array of arrays, like in this example but I don't know how to indicate it "the position of the first element in $0" ?

```
var programArray: [Any] = []

let slots: String =  "2021-14-09 08:00:00|2021-14-09 09:00:00|ACCUEIL CAFE|Amphi A#2021-14-09 09:00:00|2021-14-09 10:00:00|PLENIERE|Amphi A#2021-14-09 10:00:00|2021-14-09 12:00:00|WORKSHOP|Salle Besse#2021-14-09 12:00:00|2021-14-09 14:00:00|DEJEUNER|Cantine#2021-14-09 14:00:00|2021-14-09 16:00:00|TESTDRIVES|XXX#2021-14-09 16:00:00|2021-14-09 17:00:00|CLOTURE|Amphi A#"

//Convert Slots in array
let stringArray = slots.components(separatedBy: "#")
if stringArray.count > 1 {
    for i in 0..<stringArray.count {
        let intermediateTwo = stringArray[i]
        let strinArrayTwo = intermediateTwo.components(separatedBy: "|")
        
        if strinArrayTwo.count > 1 {
            programArray.append(strinArrayTwo)
            
        } else {
            print("not found")
        }
    }
} else {
    print("not found")
}

//Remove other dates than today
let index = programArray.firstIndex(where: {$0 == "2021-14-09"}) //PROBLEM: Cannot convert value of type 'Any' to expected argument type 'String'
    //access index here
programArray.remove(at: index)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How do you declare ```programArray.```?

Comment: var programArray: [Any] = []

Comment: @ΩlostA What about `$0 as? String == "2021-14-09"`? On another note, that is an invalid date if that's YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: As per the code, $0  is always a string array.

Comment: @George It won't work because $0 is the element of the array that is an array himself containing a String.

Comment: @ΩlostA I see, my bad.

Comment: You have an array of arrays. So declare programArray as  [[String]] and ```firstIndex(where: {$0.contains("2021-14-09")})```

Comment: @RajaKishan Perfect, that's it. It works. You can put your answer if you want I will complete it

Comment: @ΩlostA better to use regex. Btw why `[Any]` instead of `[[String]]`?

Comment: @LeoDabus I corrected it. I put [[String]] like mister Raja Kishan said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### ⚠️ Don't use `contain()` on the joined string!

The other answer and the comments are suggesting to use `contain` on the joined section. Although it may return the correct result in the specific case, Using contain will result in a fuzzy search and may result in undesired behavior like finding an unrelated object

---

#### ✅ Go the right way

First, try to clear things up:

```
var matrix = slots.split(separator: "#").map { $0.split(separator: "|") }
dump(matrix)
```

This will give you a matrix of the data:

```
▿ 6 elements
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 08:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 09:00:00"
    - "ACCUEIL CAFE"
    - "Amphi A"
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 09:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 10:00:00"
    - "PLENIERE"
    - "Amphi A"
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 10:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 12:00:00"
    - "WORKSHOP"
    - "Salle Besse"
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 12:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 14:00:00"
    - "DEJEUNER"
    - "Cantine"
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 14:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 16:00:00"
    - "TESTDRIVES"
    - "XXX"
  ▿ 4 elements
    - "2021-14-09 16:00:00"
    - "2021-14-09 17:00:00"
    - "CLOTURE"
    - "Amphi A"
```

Then search for the index you need and remove it like:

```
if let searchedIndex = matrix.firstIndex(where: { $0.first?.hasPrefix("2021-14-09") == true }) {
    matrix.remove(at: searchedIndex)
}
```

---

Also, You can join them back to the  original format like:

```
let updatedSlots = matrix.map { $0.joined(separator: "|") }.joined(separator: "#")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let index = programArray.firstIndex(where: { innerArray in
    innerArray.contains(where: { $0.hasPrefix("2021-14-09") })
})
```

Thats what you are looking for, ΩlostA?